# Возможно ли сделать такую разметку более «эстетично»?

Tags: html, css

Привет, есть такое «перетекание» границ блоков.
Реализовал таким образом: http://jsfiddle.net/gMFWc/

Есть несколько небольших вопросов:

- Может у кого нибудь будут идеи как сделать это более «эстетично»?
- Есть возможность убрать кусочки чёрной обводки по краям жёлтого блока?
- Может быть для такого стиля будет логичнее всего внедрить «резанную PNG» по середине, как вы считаете? (прошлый век, грамотно бы было иметь возможность регулировать border-radius динамически)

P.S> В голове крутится вариант с отрицательным `margin-top` у второго блока а реализовать не могу :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/gMFWc/1/

С помощью :before, :after,

```
#column0 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    width: 350px;
    margin-right: 10px;

}
#col0 {
    padding: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#col0:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -20px;
    content: "\a";
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
}
#col1 {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background: blue;
}

#col1:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -20px;
    content: "\a";
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: -1;
}
```